# Tmux Copy Mode: Show Current Line As Ascending Value From Top of Buffer

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, tmux

In this image I'm in tmux copy mode and at the very [bottom of scroll the buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aABS5.png). The line indicator on the top right shows `0/31827`. How can I show the current line number as a value that ascends from the top of the scroll buffer to the bottom? i.e. In my example, since I'm at the bottom of the scroll buffer, I'd like the line indicator to read `31827/31827` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, as confirmed by the Tmux developer in [this Github issue](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2441).

Comment: While I hate just saying, "No" to a question without providing even a hint of a workaround or anything, I'm forced to in this case.  I'd love for there to be a way to do this as well, since the current numbering scheme makes no sense to me despite the developer's explanation in that issue.  That said, in lieu of any other answers, I'd encourage you to accept and upvote this one.  BUT, please check back regularly on Super User.  It's entirely possible that someone else will come up with a good suggested workaround at some point in the future, and you can change the accepted answer if so.